# Fixing a file consisting of both UTF-8 and Windows-1252

Tags: perl, encoding, character-encoding

I have an application that produces a UTF-8 file, but some of the contents are incorrectly encoded. Some of the characters are encoded as iso-8859-1 aka iso-latin-1 or cp1252 aka Windows-1252. Is there a way of recovering the original text?

Comment: (This is a common problem in Perl resulting from decoded text being emitted without encoding.)

Comment: I don't think it's specific to Perl, Ruby and PHP suffers from the same issues. Python 3 has distinct types for bytes vs characters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes!

Obviously, it's better to fix the program creating the file, but that's not always possible. What follows are two solutions.

### A line can contain a mix of encodings

[Encoding::FixLatin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encoding::FixLatin) provides a function named `fix_latin` which decodes text that consists of a mix of UTF-8, iso-8859-1, cp1252 and US-ASCII.

```
$ perl -e'
   use Encoding::FixLatin qw( fix_latin );
   $bytes = "\xD0 \x92 \xD0\x92\n";
   $text = fix_latin($bytes);
   printf("U+%v04X\n", $text);
'
U+00D0.0020.2019.0020.0412.000A
```

Heuristics are employed, but they are fairly reliable. Only the following cases will fail:

- One of
  [ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞß]
  encoded using iso-8859-1 or cp1252, followed by one of
  [€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ`<NBSP>`¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬`<SHY>`®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿]
  encoded using iso-8859-1 or cp1252.
- One of
  [àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîï]
  encoded using iso-8859-1 or cp1252, followed by two of
  [€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ`<NBSP>`¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬`<SHY>`®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿]
  encoded using iso-8859-1 or cp1252.
- One of
  [ðñòóôõö÷]
  encoded using iso-8859-1 or cp1252, followed by two of
  [€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ`<NBSP>`¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬`<SHY>`®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿]
  encoded using iso-8859-1 or cp1252.

The same result can be produced using core module [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode), though I imagine this is a fair bit slower than Encoding::FixLatin with Encoding::FixLatin::XS installed.

```
$ perl -e'
   use Encode qw( decode_utf8 encode_utf8 decode );
   $bytes = "\xD0 \x92 \xD0\x92\n";
   $text = decode_utf8($bytes, sub { encode_utf8(decode("cp1252", chr($_[0]))) });
   printf("U+%v04X\n", $text);
'
U+00D0.0020.2019.0020.0412.000A
```

### Each line only uses one encoding

`fix_latin` works on a character level. If it's known that each line is entirely encoded using one of UTF-8, iso-8859-1, cp1252 or US-ASCII, you could make the process even more reliable by check if the line is valid UTF-8.

```
$ perl -e'
   use Encode qw( decode );
   for $bytes ("\xD0 \x92 \xD0\x92\n", "\xD0\x92\n") {
      if (!eval {
         $text = decode("UTF-8", $bytes, Encode::FB_CROAK|Encode::LEAVE_SRC);
         1  # No exception
      }) {
         $text = decode("cp1252", $bytes);
      }

      printf("U+%v04X\n", $text);
   }
'
U+00D0.0020.2019.0020.00D0.2019.000A
U+0412.000A
```

Heuristics are employed, but they are very reliable. They will only fail if **all** of the following are true for a given line:

- The line is encoded using iso-8859-1 or cp1252,
- At least one of
  [€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ`<NBSP>`¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬`<SHY>`®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷]
  is present in the line,
- All instances of
  [ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞß]
  are always followed by exactly one of
  [€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ`<NBSP>`¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬`<SHY>`®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿],
- All instances of
  [àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîï]
  are always followed by exactly two of
  [€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ`<NBSP>`¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬`<SHY>`®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿],
- All instances of
  [ðñòóôõö÷]
  are always followed by exactly three of
  [€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ`<NBSP>`¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬`<SHY>`®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿],
- None of
  [øùúûüýþÿ]
  are present in the line, and
- None of
  [€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ`<NBSP>`¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬`<SHY>`®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿]
  are present in the line except where previously mentioned.

---

Notes:

- Encoding::FixLatin installs command line tool `fix_latin` to convert files, and it would be trivial to write one using the second approach.
- `fix_latin` (both the function and the file) can be sped up by installing [Encoding::FixLatin::XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encoding::FixLatin::XS).
- The same approach can be used for mixes of UTF-8 with other single-byte encodings. The reliability should be similar, but it can vary.

Comment: Shouldn't the valid UTF-8 sequence <D0 92> be decoded as U+0412?

Comment: @chansen, Not when you know the line is encoded using cp1252, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the reasons I wrote [Unicode::UTF8](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::UTF8). With Unicode::UTF8 this is trivial using the fallback option in [Unicode::UTF8::decode_utf8()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::UTF8#decode_utf8).

```
use Unicode::UTF8 qw[decode_utf8];
use Encode        qw[decode];

print "UTF-8 mixed with Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1):\n";
for my $octets ("\xD0 \x92 \xD0\x92\n", "\xD0\x92\n") {
    no warnings 'utf8';
    printf "U+%v04X\n", decode_utf8($octets, sub { $_[0] });
}

print "\nUTF-8 mixed with CP-1252 (Windows-1252):\n";
for my $octets ("\xD0 \x92 \xD0\x92\n", "\xD0\x92\n") {
    no warnings 'utf8';
    printf "U+%v04X\n", decode_utf8($octets, sub { decode('CP-1252', $_[0]) });
}
```

Output:

```
UTF-8 mixed with Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1):
U+00D0.0020.0092.0020.0412.000A
U+0412.000A

UTF-8 mixed with CP-1252 (Windows-1252):
U+00D0.0020.2019.0020.0412.000A
U+0412.000A
```

Unicode::UTF8 is written in C/XS and only invokes the callback/fallback when encountering an Ill-formed UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: That might be a little faster than Encode::decode_utf8 (since Encode::decode_utf8's callback must produce UTF-8), but it still uses a callback. Encoding::FixLatin doesn't, so it's bound to be faster. (And if it isn't, it can be made to be faster.) It's also simpler (`fix_latin($bytes)` vs `decode_utf8($bytes, sub { decode('cp1252', $_[0]) })`)

Comment: @ikegami, Unicode::UTF8 totally outperforms Encode's implementation of UTF-8, [the becnhmark](https://gist.github.com/chansen/957956e08069f239bbab).

Comment: Nothing I said was specific to cp1252. The same thing applies to latin-1. `fix_latin($bytes)` is simpler and faster (or can necessarily be made to be faster) than `decode_utf8($bytes, sub { $_[0] })` because of the lack of a callback. (The downside is that `fix_latin` can't be used to solve other problems that yours can.)

Answer (score -1):

Recently I came across files with a severe mix of UTF-8, CP1252, and UTF-8 encoded, then interpreted as CP1252, then that encoded as UTF-8 again, that interpreted as CP1252 again, and so forth.

I wrote the below code, which worked well for me. It looks for typical UTF-8 byte sequences, even if some of the bytes are not UTF-8, but the Unicode representation of the equivalent CP1252 byte.

```
my %cp1252Encoding = (
# replacing the unicode code with the original CP1252 code
# see e.g. http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/table-iso8859-1-vs-windows-1252.html
"\x{20ac}" => "\x80",
"\x{201a}" => "\x82",
"\x{0192}" => "\x83",
"\x{201e}" => "\x84",
"\x{2026}" => "\x85",
"\x{2020}" => "\x86",
"\x{2021}" => "\x87",
"\x{02c6}" => "\x88",
"\x{2030}" => "\x89",
"\x{0160}" => "\x8a",
"\x{2039}" => "\x8b",
"\x{0152}" => "\x8c",
"\x{017d}" => "\x8e",

"\x{2018}" => "\x91",
"\x{2019}" => "\x92",
"\x{201c}" => "\x93",
"\x{201d}" => "\x94",
"\x{2022}" => "\x95",
"\x{2013}" => "\x96",
"\x{2014}" => "\x97",
"\x{02dc}" => "\x98",
"\x{2122}" => "\x99",
"\x{0161}" => "\x9a",
"\x{203a}" => "\x9b",
"\x{0153}" => "\x9c",
"\x{017e}" => "\x9e",
"\x{0178}" => "\x9f",
);
my $re = join "|", keys %cp1252Encoding;
$re = qr/$re/;
my %cp1252Decoding = reverse % cp1252Encoding;
my $cp1252Characters = join "|", keys %cp1252Decoding;

sub decodeUtf8
{
    my ($str) = @_;

    $str =~ s/$re/ $cp1252Encoding{$&} /eg;
    utf8::decode($str);
    return $str;
}

sub fixString
{
    my ($str) = @_;

    my $r = qr/[\x80-\xBF]|$re/;

    my $current;
    do {
        $current = $str;

        # If this matches, the string is likely double-encoded UTF-8. Try to decode
        $str =~ s/[\xF0-\xF7]$r$r$r|[\xE0-\xEF]$r$r|[\xC0-\xDF]$r/ decodeUtf8($&) /eg;

    } while ($str ne $current);

    # decodes any possible left-over cp1252 codes to Unicode
    $str =~ s/$cp1252Characters/ $cp1252Decoding{$&} /eg;
    return $str;
}
```

This has similar limitations as ikegami's answer, except that the same limitations are also applicable to UTF-8 encoded strings.

Comment: Never mind. I managed the rollback myself. The answer is applicable to the question, and handles more complicated encoding problems as well, so it is appropriate here.

Comment: The assumptions are similar to yours, except for the last one. A free-standing CP1252 80-7F will decode to Unicode fine. The only extra assumption is that there are no UTF-8 sequences that encode for any of the character sequences that you mention. That is unavoidable if you want to decode doubly-encoded UTF-8. It is still not a very restrictive assumption.

Comment: Maybe similar, but because the loop, there are far more. Your code fails for `encode_utf8("\xF0\xBF\xBF\xBF")`, for example. All but your solution correctly returns `"\xF0\xBF\xBF\xBF"`

Comment: `encode_utf8("\xF0\xBF\xBF\xBF")` decodes fine to Unicode F0 BF BF BF. What did you expect that to decode to?

Comment: Exactly, but your code returns `"\x{3FFFF}"` instead of `"\xF0\xBF\xBF\xBF"`.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused, because I had a slightly different version at home than posted here. Yes, that case falls under "The only extra assumption is that there are no UTF-8 sequences that encode for any of the character sequences that you mention". That is unavoidable if you want to be able to decode multiple-encode UTF-8 sequences.

Comment: Re "*That is unavoidable if you want to be able to decode multiple-encode UTF-8 sequences.*", Yet, that's not what the OP asked for, so it is avoidable.

Comment: @ikegami It is a valid answer, just with an additional assumption, and applicable to a broader range of encoding problems. I really don't see the point in posting another, almost identical question, with my answer. I fail to see how that will help people solving their encoding problems in any better way, they will just have more questions to read through.

Comment: It's just a really bad answer because of the bugs you refuse to correct.

Comment: Sorry, which bugs? You mean the fact that it will also decode doubly-encoded utf-8? That is not a bug, it's a really useful feature. And if you only have single-encoding problems, then it is a limitation of the solution , similar to the limitations that your own solution has. Or did you mean real bugs that you have not mentioned before, I am not sure what you meant?

Comment: Re "*Sorry, which bugs?*", It returns garbage instead of the correct value for certain sequences. Examples provided earlier.