# Some entities not displaying in browser

Tags: perl, html-entities

```
use HTML::Entities;
$output = encode_entities($str);
```

Sometimes the above function generates `&#xFFFD;` which does not display in a browser, like this: �

What is the problem and how can I get entities like this to display properly?

Would `encode_entities_numeric` be better instead?

EDIT: Should I use the following instead?

```
use HTML::Entities;
utf8::decode($str);
$output = encode_entities($str);
```

Comment: Too broad. It's impossible to say without additional information.

Comment: @MattJacob What do you mean?  What additional information do you need?

Comment: For example... What font are you using? What browser are you using? What do you mean by "does not display"?

Comment: No font. Firefox and IE.  It displays a little box instead.  Try putting `&#xFFFD;` into an html file and see for yourself what it looks like in a browser.

Comment: What do you mean "no font"? Even the default font is *some* font!

Comment: There is no font specified in the html.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that you have some Encoding inconsistency. Didn't tried you decode  e.g. umlaut `\x{fc}` as utf8 or sometbing like? (try enable _CHECK_ in the `Encode::(de|en)code`)

Comment: @jm666 I think you are right.  If do `decode('ISO-8859-1')` instead of `utf-8` it seems to be fine.  How can you detect the encoding of the source?

Comment: In short: _you can't_. Just imagine how you want differentiate ISO1 and ISO2? For the longer answer see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1970660/632407. :)

Comment: Technically, you can [reliably guess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28681864/589924) if you know it's between iso-8859-1 and UTF-8, but guessing in general is "somewhat harder". (The linked question is about cp1252 and UTF-8, but the same applies to iso-8859-1 and UTF-8.)

Comment: @ikegami Me somewhat missed the linked answer by you, yet.  ++ to it.

Comment: @ikegami Is it likely to be anything other than `iso-8859-1` and `utf8`?

Comment: If you have to ask, yes. This machine's console uses cp850, and this machine's OS uses your choice of cp1252 or UTF-16le. There are many more than the two encodings you mention in common use.

Comment: @ikegami Is `utf8` the main problem?  Therefore if I do `utf8::decode($str)` will that solve most of my problems?  I am just trying to create a generic function to convert characters in strings to HTML entities where necessary.

Comment: Re "*Is utf8 the main problem?*", No, the problem is surely that your code is buggy. (Note that the encoding's name is "UTF-8". The case isn't important, but the dash is. Without the dash, you are talking about an internal-to-Perl extension of UTF-8.)

Comment: @ikegami If you see the edit to my question, that is all my code is.

Comment: Liar. If that was true, `$str` would be `undef`, and `$output` would contain an empty string. You obviously had a value in `$str`, so that's NOT your entire program. You have code that placed `"\x{FFFD}"` in `$str`, and it was either intentional, or due to a bug in your code.

Comment: @ikegami What I mean is that if I use the code after "EDIT", will that be solution to my issue?

Comment: I thought that was clear from my Answer, but I rephrased it to be clearer: If you don't want `encode_entities($str)` to produce `&#xFFFD;`, don't put character `0xFFFD` in `$str`. It was probably added as the result of a character-decoding error (e.g. bad input, or bad handling of the input). You'll need to debug to find the underlying problem.

Comment: `utf8::decode($str);` makes absolutely no sense there. `$str` doesn't contain text encoded using UTF-8 if it contained character `0xFFFD`. (It will leave `$str` unchanged and return false to signal an error.)

Answer (score 2):

If `encode_entities($str)` produces `&#xFFFD;`, it's because `$str` contains character `0xFFFD`.

So if you don't want `encode_entities($str)` to produce `&#xFFFD;`, don't put character `0xFFFD` in `$str`. It was probably added as the result of a character-decoding error (e.g. bad input, or bad handling of the input). You'll need to debug to find the underlying problem.